# Remove the extended column lines and set the row height

Tags: tables

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[t]
    \caption{Improvement in Reliability}
    \label{table_example}
    \centering

    \begin{tabular}{|p{1.5em}|p{2.1em}|p{1.5 em}|p{3.3em}|p{3.3em}|p{3.3em}|p{3.3em}|p{4.25em}|p{3.3em}|p{3.3em}|p{3.3em}|p{3.3em}|p{4.25em}|}
        \hline

    \multirow{2}{1.5em}{Tasks} &
    \multirow{2}{0.30em}{Edges} &
    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Reliability}
    & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\%Improvement}   

    \\
    \cline{3-13}

    & & Ref. [12] & Same Latency & Latency 5\% & Latency 10\% & Latency 25\% & No Constraint & Same Latency & Latency 5\% & Latency 10\% & Latency 25\% & No Constraint \\[-7pt]
    \hline

    s00 &   7 & 0.923   &   0.957 & 0.958  &    0.958 & 0.984 & 0.9849 &    3.673 & 3.770&  3.770  &    6.706 & 6.706\\[-7.25pt]
    \hline

    s01 & 68 & 0.431 &  0.503 & 0.541 & 0.591 & 0.675 & 0.798 & 16.787 & 25.702 &   37.288 &    56.652 &    85.280\\[-7.25pt]

    \hline      


    s02 &   81 &    0.339 &     0.396 & 0.429 & 0.444 & 0.554 & 0.754 & 16.987 &    26.609 &    31.049 &    63.604 &    122.747 \\[-7.25pt] 


    \hline\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `\documentclass{conference}` doesn't really help without a pointer to where the class can be found.

Comment: http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html - The class was obtained from the above link for Latex templates

Comment: If I typeset the example as posted all the lines over-print each other, why have you got negative spacing between each line?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add some `\linespread`, `\baselinestretch` or `\doublespacing` command?

Answer (score 1):

There is negative spacing between each line (which is why the vertical lines over-shoot) If you remove the `[]` options to `\\` it works as expected. This shows your original and the effect without the negative space.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't produce the "extended column lines" mentioned in the title of your posting and shown in the screenshot. I did notice a doubling of the vertical lines at the start of the `\multicolumn`s for "Reliability" and "% Improvement"; it's good to remove them. You also have some negative line space adjustment directives in the code which don't show up in the screenshot; I'd remove them.

You're using a `table*` environment in order to span both columns, yet you give away quite a bit of available horizontal space. As a result, the table looks needlessly cramped. I'd use a `tabularx` environment with its width set to `\linewidth`, and I'd use (a modified form of) the `X` column type for columns 3 thru 13. That way, LaTeX will handle the column width calculations for you. Finally, I'd make use of the macros of the `booktabs` package (which you already load) and get rid of all vertical lines to "open up" the look of the table. The result of these changes is shown in the second table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[t]
\caption{Improvement in Reliability}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5em}|p{2.1em}|p{1.5em}|p{3.3em}|p{3.3em}|p{3.3em}|p{3.3em}|p{4.25em}|p{3.3em}|p{3.3em}|p{3.3em}|p{3.3em}|p{4.25em}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{1.5em}{Tasks} &
\multirow{2}{0.30em}{Edges} &
\multicolumn{6}{c|}{Reliability} & 
\multicolumn{5}{c|}{\%Improvement}   
\\
\cline{3-13}
& & Ref. [12] & Same Latency & Latency 5\% & Latency 10\% & Latency 25\% & No Constraint & Same Latency & Latency 5\% & Latency 10\% & Latency 25\% & No Constraint \\%[-7pt]
\hline
s00 &   7 & 0.923   &   0.957 & 0.958  &0.958 & 0.984 & 0.9849 &3.673 & 3.770&  3.770  &6.706 & 6.706\\%[-7.25pt]
\hline
s01 & 68 & 0.431 &  0.503 & 0.541 & 0.591 & 0.675 & 0.798 & 16.787 & 25.702 &   37.288 &56.652 &85.280\\%[-7.25pt]
\hline  
s02 &   81 &0.339 & 0.396 & 0.429 & 0.444 & 0.554 & 0.754 & 16.987 &26.609 &31.049 &63.604 &122.747 \\%[-7.25pt] 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip
\caption{Improvement in Reliability, Take 2}
\label{table_example_2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{1.5em}p{2.1em} *{11}{Y} @{}}
\toprule
Tasks & Edges &
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Reliability} & 
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\% Improvement}   
\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-8} \cmidrule(l){9-13}
& & Ref.\ [12] & Same Latency & Latency 5\% & Latency 10\% & Latency 25\% & No Constraint & Same Latency & Latency 5\% & Latency 10\% & Latency 25\% & No Constraint \\%[-7pt]
\midrule
s00 &   7 & 0.923   &   0.957 & 0.958  &0.958 & 0.984 & 0.9849 &3.673 & 3.770&  3.770  &6.706 & 6.706\\%[-7.25pt]

s01 & 68 & 0.431 &  0.503 & 0.541 & 0.591 & 0.675 & 0.798 & 16.787 & 25.702 &   37.288 &56.652 &85.280\\%[-7.25pt]

s02 &   81 &0.339 & 0.396 & 0.429 & 0.444 & 0.554 & 0.754 & 16.987 &26.609 &31.049 &63.604 &122.747 \\%[-7.25pt] 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for that solution. I'm only a beginner in LAtex, hence the obvious corrections.

Comment: I just had a quick question. In the above code, how to center certain specific columns if I want to?

Comment: @OommenMathews - I'd first create a centered version of the `X` column type, e.g., via `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}` in the preamble, and then use `C` instead of `Y` for the column(s) in question. If you need to specify an explicit column width, I'd specify \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}` in the preamble, and type `P{<width>}` instead of `p{<width>}` in the table header.